# How to identify anonymous methods in System.Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-methods

How can you identify anonymous methods via reflection?

Comment: Could you say some more about what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the attributes of the method, and see if the method is decorated with [CompilerGeneratedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx).

Anonymous methods (as well as other objects, such as auto-implemented properties, etc) will have this attribute added.

---

For example, suppose you have a type for your class.  The anonymous methods will be in:

```
Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass);
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> anonymousMethods = myClassType
    .GetMethods(
          BindingFlags.NonPublic
        | BindingFlags.Public 
        | BindingFlags.Instance 
        | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(method => 
          method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)).Any());
```

This should return any anonymous methods defined on `MyClass`.

Comment: And so can any other method (or member/type).

Comment: True - you can define this manually on any method, and fool it, but typically, this is used for anonymous methods and other compiler generated information.

Comment: For auto properties too, and on property getters and setters.

Comment: Granted, this is not a fail-safe way to do this, as there is no such thing as "anonymous", but "anonymous" typically means a compiler-generated type.

Comment: @Leppie: I just changed the language - that help?

Comment: leppie - auto property getter/setter methods have the IsAccessor == true.

Comment: This does not work on UWP for some reason. The attribute is not there.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot, because there is no such thing as an anonymous method on IL level - they're all named, and all belong to named types. And the way C# and VB compilers translate anonymous methods to named methods and types is entirely implementation-defined, and cannot be relied on (which means that, for example, it can change with any update, even in minor releases / hotfixes).

Comment: +1: This is, technically, the "correct" answer - but [CompilerGenerated] works fairly reliably in practice.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see, that Regex pattern would be:

```
<(\w|_)+>b_.+
```